# Am I allowed to make multiple apps with the same template and code on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

So imagine that I want to create many apps with exactly the same code but only changing images of the app. Am I allowed to do that on Google Play? I know this question was awnsered but the other post was asked 5 years ago, so maybe things have changed. Thank you.

Comment: I guess yes, why not?

Comment: I remember someone told me that it was not possible to publish apps with the same code and that all apps must be different not even similar

Comment: An instance I can remember is Telegram (its android client is open source) and an uncountable number of developers have published their custom Telegram clients with different name/logo. Most of them only add some Google Ads banners on the source code and sometimes few features and their codes are at most, less than 1% different!

Comment: As long as package name is different and there is no policy violation you can publish your app with same code base.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an official reference that proves this is true?

Comment: I can't provide you with any official references but this how whitelabel apps are developed. Just make sure you are not copying anyone's work and violating policies.

Comment: What do you mean copying anyone's work? Do you mean making an app that is similar to another app on the Google Play? What would happen if you develop it and it is similar to another app but you didn´t copy it but the resulting app is similar? And also you can not copy your own apps?

Answer (score 2):

## No

No you are not allowed to do this and **BE VERY CAREFUL**.. Google will find you and block your entire account. it happened to too many developers.

Under Google's [Spam and Minimum Functionality](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9899034?hl=en#zippy=%2Cexamples-of-common-violations) policy violation:

> **Repetitive Content**
>
> We don't allow apps that merely provide the same experience as other apps already on Google Play. Apps should provide value to users through the creation of unique content or services.
>
> **Examples of common violations**
>
> - Creating multiple apps with highly similar functionality, content, and user experience. If these apps are each small in content volume, developers should consider creating a single app that aggregates all the content

Comment: @rayo7 was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?

Comment: It seems this policy is only getting more restrictive. Am I right in thinking that now it is also not allowed to have repetetive apps with different developer accounts?

Comment: @HansDash yes, you can't even have repetitive apps with different developer account unless you are developing an app for multiple businesses and every copy has a significant change than the original template. I know a development company that sold a template for more than 1k developers, apple removed all the copies from app store and just kept the original template demo app. Also google suspended all developers accounts.